# A mass is sliding from a frictionless hill into a sliding board with friction, find work of friction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation

Hey I have some I don't really understand here:

[image]

The mass m slides into the mass M $(m \neq M)$ which is a sliding board(it can move freely without friction from the ground). There is only friction between mass m and mass M.
What happens is the ball slides into the board, with beginning velocity of 
$v = \sqrt{2gh}$.

After a while the relative speed between the board and the ball is 0 ( they are still moving together in the same speed).

I think since the friction is relative to the board, so does the Work, that means that the final relative speed is 0 and the beginning relative speed is $mgh$ which means :

$W = \Delta E_{k} = 0 - mgh = -mgh$

I heard it's not correct but I don't know why, do I need to use Conservation of Momentum, but is there Conservation of Momentum with friction which is non conversative force?

in short :

1)Why am I wrong ?

2)Can I use Conversation of Momentum ? Does it exist here with the friction ?

Comment: Is the ball *sliding* down the hill, or *rolling w/o slipping*?

Comment: I guess you'd handle this like a fully inelastic collision.

Comment: @Gert if it was rolling the rotational energy would not "contribute" to forward momentum. In this case wouldn't you need the ball dimensions to subtract it properly?

Comment: You are confusing many different things: do you remember when Linear Momentum is conserved? When the system is ...: does this apply to the system comprised by the two masses *m* and *M*, once *m* has moved onto *M*? Also, reconsider: if friction is a non-conservative force, does this really impact the conservation of Linear Momentum? Or perhaps, the conservation of linear momentum is tied to something completely unrelated to dissipative character of friction....

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Oh I think I confused conservation of momentum and energy ? After reviewing conservation of momentum happens when the external force on the system is 0. So it does happen in this case. But on the other hand why my work calculation is wrong ?

Comment: Is $m=M$? If not, what should you change?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Sorry I needed to make the more clear $m \neq M$, I need to calculate the work the friction does on the mass $m$ when it's on the board.

Comment: Please clean up the question.  Is $m$ rolling or sliding?  is $M$ fixed or free to move over the ground with no friction?   Your units and notation is wrong.  $W$ can't possibly be $\sqrt{2gh}$, the units are wrong.

Comment: @garyp Sorry thought I edited all the "rolling" out of it, forgot one. And fixed  $W$, although it doesn't mean it is really $W$ it's just what I'm questioning. $M$ is a sliding board as mentioned so it can freely move without friction with the ground as there is only friction between him and $m$

Comment: Ok, I get it.   I'll point out that the final kinetic energy is not zero.  Both masses are moving.

Comment: @garyp Ok ye  I looked into that and it  seems like work energy relation only works from a bystander prespective and not relatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found out the answer to my question so I'll answer it here :

1) The work energy relation is from an observational frame of reference, so to calculate the work the friction did, I need to calculate the kinetic energy difference between when the  friction just started applying and when it ended from an observational frame of reference.
Because it was the only force applied, the work done on the object m will be the work done by the friction.

2) to calculate the work I'll need final speed of the body which I'll get from conservation of momentum which does apply here because there are no external forces on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Momentum is always conserved **within a closed system**, even when there are  (internal) friction forces. The fact that the block $M$ slides freely makes $m, M$ a closed system from the time at which $m$ leaves contact with the ramp.

When $m$ reaches the bottom of the slope it has momentum $mv$. Assuming that the mass $m$ eventually comes to rest on block $M$, then together they have momentum $(m+M)V$ where $V<v$ is their common final velocity. Momentum is conserved so $mv=(m+M)V$.

The work done against friction while the relative velocity between $m$ and $M$ was being reduced to zero is the loss of KE,which is $\frac12mv^2 - \frac12(m+M)V^2$.

Comment: Momentum would not  be conserved if the friction is external to the system; watch out how you word that phrase.   Also, to my eye this is very close to being a complete answer, something we try to avoid, as you know.

Answer (score -1):

The ball will reach the sliding mass M and start sliding on it's surface. Friction between the 2 will increase the speed of M (if it's free to move) and reduce the speed of ball relative to ground. At a certain time t speed of both of them would become equal (stopping relative motion) and then friction will stop acting.
There is no such thing as relative friction or relative force, it's called a *pseudoforce*. Also,conservation of momentum is valid as long as the external force on system is 0, which is true in this case.